# WebBrowser strange behaviour with margins

Tags: layout, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, margin

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I have a user control with the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXXXXXX.Views.SignIn.FacebookControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <!--ContentPanel. Colocar aquí el contenido adicional-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Height="30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Visibility="Visible" 
                Margin="10"
                Name="LoadingText"
                Text="{Binding Path=AppResources.BrowserNavigating, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
            <phone:WebBrowser
                Grid.Row="0"
                Name="FacebookLoginBrowser"
                IsScriptEnabled="True"
                Height="607"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="0,10"
                Navigated="FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated"
                Loaded="FacebookLoginBrowser_Loaded"
                Navigating="FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigating"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm a get this:
[image: WebBrowser margin error]

`WebBrowser` has a left margin, bigger than its right margin.

**UPDATE**
And this is how I'm embedding my user control:

```
facebookControl = new FacebookControl();
facebookControl.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 2);
facebookControl.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
facebookControl.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
facebookControl.Margin = new Thickness(0);
facebookControl.Height = 768;
facebookControl.Width = 480;
ContentPanel.Children.Add(facebookControl);
```

And this is the definition for ContentPanel:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your line `Margin="0,10"` may have something to do with it. Have you tried setting it to a single number so that all the margins are the same?

Comment: @johnhforrest: I've changed to 0 and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ContentPanel` grid has margins (of 12px) on both sides but the right one is not as obvious with the performance counters displayed. Is this the issue?

Comment: Kill the app in VS2010 then run it manually on the emulator (similar to how you would start an app on your phone). I think there is a way to do it programatically so you don't lose debugging information but that is the quick and dirty way to do it.

Comment: I've changed my question with a new photo without performance counters. I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The margins are unbalanced because you're explicitly setting the **Width**. Don't specifically set the **Width** or **HorizontalAlignment** on `facebookControl` and it should fill the available space and be visually balanced.